# SQL Server 2019, SQL Server Agent service doesn't auto-load - error 776, token supplied to function is invalid

Tags: sql-server, windows-server-2019

I noticed after a recent update to Windows 2019, our lone server running Active Directory, that several related SQL Server services were no longer starting.

After researching each of those errors, I was able to get them running, leaving SQL Server Agent as the only one left to troubleshoot. I can start it manually, it runs for 10 seconds, then shuts down.

After researching, things I've tried:

1. SERVICES > SQL SERVER AGENT > LOG ON, I changed this to Local System Account and ticked Allow Service To Interact With Desktop
2. SERVICES > SQL SERVER AGENT > GENERAL, I changed Startup Type to Automatic (Delayed Start)
3. SERVICES > SQL SERVER AGENT > Recovery > First Failure, I set to restart the service
4. SERVICES > SQL SERVER AGENT > Recovery > Second Failure, I set to restart the service

Contents of SQLAGENT.OUT

```
2023-06-15 09:25:53 - ? [508] Logging SQL Server Agent messages in file 'E:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL15.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Log\SQLAGENT.OUT'.
2023-06-15 09:25:53 - ? [000] Event Global\sqlserverRecComplete opened
2023-06-15 09:25:53 - ? [100] Microsoft SQLServerAgent version 15.0.2101.7 (X64 unicode retail build) : Process ID 8028
2023-06-15 09:25:53 - ? [495] The SQL Server Agent startup service account is XXX\SA200$.
2023-06-15 09:25:53 - ! [150] SQL Server does not accept the connection (error: 776). Waiting for Sql Server to allow connections. Operation attempted was: Verify Connection On Start.
2023-06-15 09:25:54 - ! [150] SQL Server does not accept the connection (error: 776). Waiting for Sql Server to allow connections. Operation attempted was: Verify Connection On Start.
2023-06-15 09:25:55 - ! [150] SQL Server does not accept the connection (error: 776). Waiting for Sql Server to allow connections. Operation attempted was: Verify Connection On Start.
2023-06-15 09:25:56 - ! [150] SQL Server does not accept the connection (error: 776). Waiting for Sql Server to allow connections. Operation attempted was: Verify Connection On Start.
2023-06-15 09:25:57 - ! [150] SQL Server does not accept the connection (error: 776). Waiting for Sql Server to allow connections. Operation attempted was: Verify Connection On Start.
2023-06-15 09:25:58 - ! [150] SQL Server does not accept the connection (error: 776). Waiting for Sql Server to allow connections. Operation attempted was: Verify Connection On Start.
2023-06-15 09:25:59 - ! [150] SQL Server does not accept the connection (error: 776). Waiting for Sql Server to allow connections. Operation attempted was: Verify Connection On Start.
2023-06-15 09:26:00 - ! [150] SQL Server does not accept the connection (error: 776). Waiting for Sql Server to allow connections. Operation attempted was: Verify Connection On Start.
2023-06-15 09:26:01 - ! [150] SQL Server does not accept the connection (error: 776). Waiting for Sql Server to allow connections. Operation attempted was: Verify Connection On Start.
2023-06-15 09:26:02 - ! [150] SQL Server does not accept the connection (error: 776). Waiting for Sql Server to allow connections. Operation attempted was: Verify Connection On Start.
2023-06-15 09:26:03 - ! [150] SQL Server does not accept the connection (error: 776). Waiting for Sql Server to allow connections. Operation attempted was: Verify Connection On Start.
2023-06-15 09:26:04 - ! [150] SQL Server does not accept the connection (error: 776). Waiting for Sql Server to allow connections. Operation attempted was: Verify Connection On Start.
2023-06-15 09:26:05 - ! [150] SQL Server does not accept the connection (error: 776). Waiting for Sql Server to allow connections. Operation attempted was: Verify Connection On Start.
2023-06-15 09:26:06 - ! [150] SQL Server does not accept the connection (error: 776). Waiting for Sql Server to allow connections. Operation attempted was: Verify Connection On Start.
2023-06-15 09:26:07 - ! [150] SQL Server does not accept the connection (error: 776). Waiting for Sql Server to allow connections. Operation attempted was: Verify Connection On Start.
2023-06-15 09:26:07 - ! [000] Unable to connect to server '(local)'; SQLServerAgent cannot start
2023-06-15 09:26:07 - ! [298] SQLServer Error: 776, SQL Server Network Interfaces: The token supplied to the function is invalid [SQLSTATE HY000] 
2023-06-15 09:26:07 - ! [298] SQLServer Error: 776, Cannot generate SSPI context [SQLSTATE HY000] 
2023-06-15 09:26:07 - ! [382] Logon to server '(local)' failed (DisableAgentXPs)
2023-06-15 09:26:07 - ? [098] SQLServerAgent terminated (normally)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Additional Info

In terms of what may have influenced this behaviour, we had a catastrophic failure of the internet telephone line at the premises the day before. The quickest solution was to swap out the existing domestic router with a new one, which uses a sim card / 4G connection. The new router was given same IP address as previous one and its DHCP server was set up with same scope.

This then led me down a new rabbit hole, explaining how an SSPI > SPN error may have come about

[article on Cannot Generate SSPI context](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/sql/database-engine/connect/cannot-generate-sspi-context-error)

result of SQLCHECK...

```
Suggested SPN                       Exists  Status                                                                                   
--------------------------------    ------  -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
MSSQLSvc/SA200.ad.redacted.net:1433     False   SPN is on the wrong account: Administrator, CN=Administrator,CN=Users,DC=ad,DC=redacted,DC=net
MSSQLSvc/SA200:1433                 False   SPN does not exist.                                                                      
MSSQLSvc/SA200.ad.redacted.net          False   SPN is on the wrong account: Administrator, CN=Administrator,CN=Users,DC=ad,DC=redacted,DC=net
MSSQLSvc/SA200                      False   SPN does not exist.
```

I suspect this SPN issue could be down to me initially using the wrong solution to fix the SQLSERVER service - I altered the log on as to local service which I think may cause the above SPN issue. All I needed do was select delayed start. I'll try and set the SQLSERVER service back to log on as NT AUTHORITY/Network Service tonight and re-run SQLCHECK to see if it solves the SPN issue

UPDATE 22nd July 2023

Added 2 missing SPN's using SETSPN -s ...

SETSPN -s MSSQLSvc/SA200 (computername)

SETSPN -s MSSQLSvc/SA200:1433 (computername)

the 2 other SPN's I cant seem to remove and add back in...

MSSQLSvc/SA200.ad.redacted.net

MSSQLSvc/SA200.ad.redacted.net:1433

I can remove them with SETSPN -d but when I try to add either back in, it tells me duplicates detected

Comment: Have tried to see if Shared Memory and Named Pipes protocols are enabled? Please enable them and restart SQL Server service using SQL Server Configuration Manager.

Comment: enabled - restarted but problem persists

Answer (score 1):

In the SQL Server administrator we noticed the service for SQLServer Agent was logging in with the local user account - we changed this to the correct NT Service\SQLServerAgent and problem was corrected

Regards the SPN errors detailed by SQLCheck, we corrected those by using SETSPN -d to first remove each one, being careful to use the correct account name (or else they won't be removed). We then created new SPN's for each with the -s option. Re-running SQLCheck showed no errors